# How can I keep the vertical lines under the horizontal ruler line is chartjs?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Chartjs Version: 3.7.0
(any guru suggesting another version? comment below!)

I have this code:

```
<script>
new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [1800,1850,1900],
    datasets: [{ 
        data: [86,114,106],
        label: "Africa",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [282,350,411],
        label: "Asia",
        borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [168,170,178],
        label: "Europe",
        borderColor: "#3cba9f",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [40,20,10],
        label: "Latin America",
        borderColor: "#e8c3b9",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [6,3,2],
        label: "North America",
        borderColor: "#c45850",
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'World population per region (in millions)'
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

and this chart looks like this:

[image]

**Question**:
How can I keep the lines I have circled with red in the picture below but remove the lines I have circled with yellow ? (I want to remove all the vertical lines).

[image]

I want to make it look (wireframe wise) like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the `xAxes` gridlines. See the documentation [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.3.0/axes/styling.html). Example:

```js
var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: [1500, 1550, 1600, 1650, 1700, 1750, 1800, 1850, 1900],
    datasets: [{
      data: [86, 114, 106, 86, 114, 106, 86, 114, 106, 86, 114, 106],
      label: "Africa",
      borderColor: "#3e95cd",
      fill: false
    }, {
      data: [282, 350, 411, 282, 350, 411, 282, 350, 411, 282, 350, 411],
      label: "Asia",
      borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
      fill: false
    }, {
      data: [168, 170, 178, 168, 170, 178, 168, 170, 178, 168, 170, 178],
      label: "Europe",
      borderColor: "#3cba9f",
      fill: false
    }, {
      data: [40, 20, 10, 40, 20, 10, 40, 20, 10, 40, 20, 10, 40, 20, 10],
      label: "Latin America",
      borderColor: "#e8c3b9",
      fill: false
    }, {
      data: [6, 3, 2, 6, 3, 2, 6, 3, 2, 6, 3, 2, 6, 3, 2],
      label: "North America",
      borderColor: "#c45850",
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
            }
        }],
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-zoom@0.7.5/dist/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="myChartDiv" style="width: 600px;">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you only want to hide the gridlines inside the drawing area you can set `drawOnChartArea: false`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70494179/1996066) great answer below.

Comment: Ok, but how can I keep the small pieces of the veritcal lines, that are circled with red in the screenshot I attatched?

Answer (score 2):

You pass in options > scales > x > grid > display:false

Example:

```
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: { grid:{ display:false } }, // will hide vertical gridlines
      y: { grid:{ display:true } } // will show horizontal gridlines
    },
  }
});
```

So in your case:

```
<script>
new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [1800,1850,1900],
    datasets: [{ 
        data: [86,114,106],
        label: "Africa",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [282,350,411],
        label: "Asia",
        borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [168,170,178],
        label: "Europe",
        borderColor: "#3cba9f",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [40,20,10],
        label: "Latin America",
        borderColor: "#e8c3b9",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [6,3,2],
        label: "North America",
        borderColor: "#c45850",
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'World population per region (in millions)'
    },
    scales: {
      x: { grid:{ display:false } },
      y: { grid:{ display:true } }
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: It seems that, this options do not keep the small vertical lines under the ruler horizontal line. But instead it just remove the horizontal lines completely.

Comment: @JameuLukasli1 if I understand correctly, you want to hide the vertical lines but keep their "ending" in the horizontal ruler? If yes, I don't believe it's possible.

Comment: You understood correctly. Sadly you are most probably right, because I couldnt find out an option or a way to achieve this inside the documentation.

Comment: @GeorgeChond it is possible, you can check my answer to see how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70494179/8682983

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `drawOnChartArea` in the grid options to false, also your title does not work since its configured in the wrong namespace, it has to be configured in the `plugins` section:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        grid: {
          drawOnChartArea: false
        }
      },
      x: {
        grid: {
          drawOnChartArea: false
        }
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Title of the chart'
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Followed up your solution and done implementing ```onHover``` but I am facing little issue here https://stackoverflow.com/q/70496991/15916627 .. Could you please kindly help me out here. More thanks in advance.